# IP Address Deny Manager does not seem to work

Tags: cpanel, block

I blocked an IP trying login attempts through **IP Address Deny Manager** on cpanel but it doesn't seem to work. I still see the blocked IP on my visitor log? If IP Address Deny Manager is not helpful, how can I limit that IP?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't enabled mod_rewrite. Apache does not simply use it without the module being enabled for this particular feature. If your VPS or Dedicated then run `sudo a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart`, or alternatively contact your web host.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache, edit the .htaccess file in your website root directory and add the below. 192.0.2.123 will represent the IP address of the user you wish to block.

```
order allow,deny
deny from 192.0.2.123
allow from all
```

If you are using NginX, edit the vhosts config file (location depends on your setup) and add the below.

```
location / {
    deny  192.0.2.123;
    allow all;
}
```

Note: You would have to reload/restart apache.nginx for changes to take effect.

Comment: I checked the .htaccess, it is already there.

Comment: Could the log just be dodgy? Perhaps the log is showing attempted access?

Comment: For Apache to pay attention to .htaccess directives, you need `AllowOverride AuthConfig` in effect. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride Note that the default changed from `All` to `None` with the release of Apache 2.3.9!

Comment: @Craig It is generally recommended to use the thus reserved IP address ranges and DNS names for documentation and examples. Those are spread out across various RFCs; I have put together a summary on my personal web site at https://michael.kjorling.se/computers/internet-reservations/examples-and-documentation.

Comment: @Michael Good shout. I hadn't considered that.